# Double shielding in the response from the controller

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

An entity with an indissoluble gap comes to the controller. He additionally shields it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc/")
class Controller(
    private val service: service
) {

    @GetMapping("/byId/{id}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    suspend fun getEntity(
        @PathVariable id: Long,
    ) : EntityResponse {
        val entity = service.getEntity(id)
        println(entity)
        return entity
    }
}
```

In println, I see that the non-breaking space is not escaped.

I get: EntityResponse(statusCode=200, id=2, test=Text with\I00A0 non-explosive space)

At the same time, in insomnia I see the following answer: { "statusCode": 200, "id": 2, "test": "Text with\\I00A0 non-explosive space", }

Please help me with the solution

On this issue, I have found solutions for python or to solve problems in url parsing. It doesn't suit me.

Comment: Well it's json so the backslash must be escaped..?

Comment: There is not enough information here to know what is going on, e.g. (1) precisely the GET request made, (2) you don't show what `service.getEntity(id)` implements - is that even relevant? You suggest there is a problem with `id` decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when adding such symbols to the database! It was perceived that I was not adding a non-breaking space, but a line with the characters \I00A0. Even \uI00A0 was perceived as symbols. It is important that when added to the database or, for example, in json, this symbol is displayed as NBSP